# command line smart selection

Tags: command-line

Is there a way, in a command line tool like `cp` to be, upon pressing "tab", in a "narrowing" mode until the first argument is uniquely selected by "enter"

A bit like Helm in emacs, or [Z](https://github.com/rupa/z)

Comment: Might be interesting for you https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

Comment: Are you asking about bash tab completion? Where you can enter part of a command  or file name press tab and one of two things happen. Either completion or the printing of all possible completions so you can enter some more characters then press tab again.

Comment: @rhubarbdog indeed, but one with more advanced feature. helm for instance helm is "reactive", can make smart guesses etc